# How to shedule logstash using a REST service based on java?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, logstash, filebeat

I'm developing a tool which can identify dependencies between errors of my error log. This tool is being developed using filebeat and logstash to read log file data and the java REST service is used to identify dependencies between errors. So the outcome will be a web page that displays error dependencies. The log files are located in a remote location and are updated daily. My intention is to host my web service and give users in remote locations the access to view my web service with the result. So I'm planning to make my REST service run daily. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: It's not clear what setup do you have: where log files in relation to log readers, and why do you specifically need to have a REST service there? What would that rest service do? Will it start readers that would run on same machine and then post result, or will it stream log files over to remote readers?

Comment: I'm developing a tool which can identify dependencies between errors of my error log. This tool is being developed using filebeat and logstash to read log file data and the java REST service is used to identify dependencies between errors. So the outcome will be a web page that displays error dependencies. The log files are located in a remote location and are updated daily. My intention is to host my web service and give users in remote locations the access to view my web service with the result. So I'm planning to make my REST service run daily. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: Cool. Can you please add all this into the actual question? Also: REST means not what you think it means - the REST service would be what gives your users access to results produced by your tool, not the tool itself (unless you use REST endpoints to allow users to point your tool at some specific file location(s)). You can learn more about it [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html), for example.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Ok. I'll add them. So any idea for performing this scheduling?